# How can I copy the path of a file in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, uti

How can I copy the path to a folder or a file? The Info Dialog doesn't allow me to copy the information that stands there ...

[image]

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Are you not able to highlight the value next to "Where:" and press `CMD+c` to copy it?

Comment: @ayaz consider writing that as an answer, since it's probably the best way to do what he's asking :)

Comment: which version are you on? If I right click on the path, I get the standard edit menu with `Copy` in it

Comment: Related: [How I can copy to the clipboard the path (or the full url) of a file or a folder?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119958/how-i-can-copy-to-the-clipboard-the-path-or-the-full-url-of-a-file-or-a-folder/)

Answer (score 46):

Right click on the file, hold down <kbd>Alt/Option</kbd>, and an item to copy file path will appear as `Copy "<FILENAME>" as Pathname`.

This is the easiest option for day to day usage, without involving Automator.

This seems to be a relatively new feature that was added in OS X El Capitan. (It also works on macOS Sierra).

Comment: an even easier option is to click the Finder **Edit** menu, press the **Option** key and then _Copy xyz_ will turn into _Copy xyz as pathname_ — easier than right-clicking which requires an extra finger.

Comment: Interesting, cool to know! I guess it's easier if you use control+click. I always use a two finger tap on the trackpad or a physical right click on a mouse.

Comment: Note: Doing alt+right-click (holding the alt key while you right-click) doesn't work; you need to right-click, and _then_ hold the alt key.

Comment: or just `opt+cmd+C` pure keyboard shortcut

Comment: @JonSchneider for me, it doesn't matter when you press the Alt key—as long as you are eventually pressing it while the right-click menu shows up, the option will appear

Answer (score 13):

Starting in El Capitan (OS X v10.11), this is really easy:

1. Select the item(s) in the Finder
2. Press <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> (or hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key down and choose Edit menu > Copy [whatever] as Pathname.

Comment: There really needs to be a way to pin this to the top as "Best Answer Which Was Not Available At Time When Question Was Asked."

Comment: Oh yes, this is it. All the answers were about copying path by selecting folder first, but I wanted path from inside of the folder. I've opened a folder, I'm here I want a path. Command-Option-C solves the problem. Added to touchbar ;d

Answer (score 11):

As already described by ayaz, the Get Info window (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>) has the full path and will allow you to copy it. If you *tripple* click in the highlighted area (by the red rectangle) the selection will automatically expand to the whole path. <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> will suffice to copy it to the clipboard.

[image: get info window]

If you need the path to interact with the Terminal, you can always check one of the “zillion” answers in this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/420456/2684).

**UPDATE**: This method seems to be only valid for OS X 10.6.x, previous OS X versions used the non-POSIX path style that looked like path:to:file, whereas the POSIX would be path/to/file. If you are in something older than OS X 10.6, you will have to try one of the other methods described in the other answers (or upgrade to 10.6 ;)

Comment: I don't know why but this doesn't work for me. There is no selection at all in this dialog.

Comment: What OS version do you have?

Comment: This doesn't work for me either, running 10.5.8

Comment: The info method not working might be a 10.5 vs. 10.6 issue. I just noticed for the first time that the path displayed is POSIX style and not the long-standing "path:to:file" style.

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways I do this (and the info window is neither of them):

1. Open the Terminal application and drag the item into the window, and a POSIX-style path will be displayed that you can copy and paste.
2. Use Applescript...

...select an item in the Finder and run this...

```
tell application "Finder"
    return info for selection as alias
end tell
```

...or create a droplet with this code...

```
on open theFile
   set thePath to POSIX path of theFile
   set the clipboard to thePath as text
end open
```

Add salt to taste.

Comment: Any application that [cannot receive files or file contents after a drap and drop](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Tasks/DraggingFiles.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001288-CEGJFDFG) will give you the filename instead. So this not only works with Terminal, but also with TextEdit or other "simple" apps.

Answer (score 5):

The best and easiest way to do this is by creating a "copy path" service, very similar to the <kbd>shift</kbd> + Right-Click on a Windows machine.

If you frequently need to copy and paste file and folder paths, creating an Automator Service will make your life easier because the service then becomes accessible from the OS X Right-Click contextual menu, accessible from anywhere in the Finder.

Follow these steps to set it up  (screenshots below).

1. Launch Automator
2. Create a new “Service”
3. Use the search function to look for “Copy to Clipboard” and drag that into the rightsize panel of the Service Set ‘Service receives selected’ to “files or folders” and ‘in’ to “Finder”.
4. Save the Service with a name like “Copy Path”.

   [image]

The result:

[image]

You'll now have the textual path in your clipboard.

Sources: [CNet](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-copy-a-file-path-in-os-x/),
[OSX Daily](http://osxdaily.com/2013/06/19/copy-file-folder-path-mac-os-x/)

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Shame that Apple did not enable such a simple conf as the default ... It took MSFT 5 years to implement the copy as path right menu item after countless regedit and dll hacks were invented by the community ... such a good example of the fact that big companies do not really study carefully the needs of their customers ...

Comment: In Mojave, `Service` is now called `Quick action` (a great innovation, goes without saying.)

Comment: I upvoted this despite that step 3 is a nightmare of a sentence that is impossible to understand. I hope you can edit this step so I (and other possible users) can get this working.

Answer (score 3):

Simply drag the file into text editor, and it will give you the full path for that file.

Answer (score 3):

Method 1:
In macOS holding the `ALT key`(⌥) often shows extra options in context menus.
`Copy "item" as Pathname`.
Detail https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/318007/302207
[image: detail]

---

Method 2:
If you use TotalFinder, you can [Allow path copying from Context Menus](https://totalfinder.binaryage.com/menus)

> TotalFinder makes it really easy to capture a variety of path formats for a selected object. Right-click on any file or folder, select Copy Path, and select the path format you'd like copied to the clipboard.

[image: images_context-menu-path]

TotalFinder setting path:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is how to create a Service to copy to the clipboard the selected paths in Finder:

1. Open Automator. Press ⌘+N and choose Service.
2. Set "Service receives selected `files or folders` in `Finder.app`".
3. Drag the element "Run Shell Script" to the window.
   *Note: You can select this element if you go to the left of the window and click on Actions, Library, and type part of the name in the search box.*
4. Set "Shell: `/bin/bash`", "Pass input: `as arguments`" and type the following in the script box: `for f in "$@" do echo "$f" done`.
5. Drag the element Copy to Clipboard.
6. Save your service in `~/Library/Services/Copy POSIX Paths.workflow` (or any other name you like).

Now you will be able to run this service if you right click an element and choose Services > Copy POSIX Paths. It will copy the file(s) selected in Finder to your clipboard. I tested this on Lion.

[image: Automator]

I got this tip from [Kris Johnson's Blog](http://undefinedvalue.com/2009/11/05/automator-service-copy-file-paths-clipboard).

Answer (score 0):

I will move my comment over as an answer.

You should be able to copy the path to a folder/file by highlighting the value next to "Where:" in the info dialog and pressing `CMD+c`.

An easier alternative that requires less effort is right-clicking on that value, and clicking "Copy" in the drop-down that appears.

Comment: Doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 0):

1. Start automator
2. Create a new service
3. Set the service to acquire files and folder in the finder, and add the run applescript element
4. Paste this script

   ```
   on run {input, parameters}
   set mylist to {}
   repeat with elem in input
       try
           set the end of mylist to (POSIX path of (elem as alias))
       end try
   end repeat
   set oldtid to AppleScript's text item delimiters


   set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {return}
   set flatlist to mylist as text


   set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldtid


   tell application "Finder" to set the clipboard to flatlist


   -- code below will also create an email with the path inside. delete it if you don't want that.
   tell application "Microsoft Entourage"
       set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:myFileName, content:flatlist}
       open theMessage
       activate
   end tell
   end run
   ```
5. Save the result as 'copy and email path' or something.
6. Now check your ctrl-click menu and your services menu. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the solution is so simple.

Just mark the file in the finder and then press Command-C. The path including the file name is copied to the clipboard and you can paste it in any application.

Comment: I just got the filename in the clipboard. How Do You get the full path ?

Comment: In the finder, click once on the filename or the icon so that the file is highlighted (if you can change the filename now, you clicked to often and you must press Escape to cancel the rename operation). Then press Command-C.

Comment: doesn't work for me either, just the filename is copied.

Comment: I just checked it. It works when pasting into Terminal but not into TextEdit.

Dragging and dropping a file into Terminal pastes the filename and path. Dito in TextEdit. What about other applications?